# What aspects of macroeconomics should I address for convincing an investor to invest in a certain country?

Tags: banking, investment, financial-markets

I have a task at my internship which is to write 2 pages about the economic conditions in my country. My question is what I could include in my research. Surely, I'll address inflation, currency fluctuations since they are very unstabe. What else can I add? Where can I get reports on a certain country, in this case is Egypt.

Comment: Supranational bodies like the IMF would be a good place to start, or the central bank.

Comment: Key risk factors? Political risk? Corporate governance risk? Valuation (eg. P/E type stuff)? Correlation with other markets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said, international organisations are a good place to start. For example, the World Bank publishes periodic economic outlook updates on each country. For Egypt, see [here](http://www.worldbank.org/en/country/egypt/publication/economic-outlook-april-2017). There is a pdf link to the right of the page. They covers aspects like GDP growth, inflation, financial and fiscal accounts, and also some prospects on ongoing, pro-business reforms.

Another source is the African Economic Outlook reports. [Here](http://www.africaneconomicoutlook.org/en/country-notes/egypt) is the one for Egypt. This is a bit more broad, including analysis of debt, revenues and spending, monetary policy, governance, natural resources management, and the social sphere (poverty, social protection, gender equality). See also the website of the IMF [dedicated to Egypt](http://www.imf.org/external/country/egy/).

Finally, having worked in the financial sector for a few years, I know that most of the investment banks produce periodic reports on every country their clients might have investment interests, reports that usually include a lot of forecasts. Albeit most of these reports are not available to the public, some googling still yield some results. For example, [here](http://enterprise.press/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/DB_SpecialReport_2017-06-05.pdf) is a **very comprehensive** analysis for Egypt from Deutsche Bank, published two months ago.  Other asset management companies also produce such reports (e.g [here](http://www.lazardassetmanagement.co.uk/institutional-investor/docs/sp0/10407/EmergingMarketsSovereign-Egypt_en.pdf?pagename=Emerging+Markets+Sovereign+Outlook)).